# Props don't pass to custom top bar title components in React Native Navigation v2

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm trying to pass props into a custom top bar title component. The below code works fine on iOS however the props don't get passed into the title component on Android.

Am I missing something here? It seems to be related to this issue.
https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3498

```
Navigation.showModal({
stack: {
  children: [{
    component: {
      name: 'screenName',
      options: {
        topBar: {
          title: {
            component: {
              passProps: {
                title: 'title',
              }
            },
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

});

https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3498

Answer (score 1):

[This was just fixed](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/commit/c7cb591c3fad3bbdfc91085691cb89012ec03923), published in 2.0.2466

Comment: It would be beneficial to add a snippet or code that fixes the issue, since the links might change and reference wouldn't be available.